# Recoil atom/atomFamily deep comparison

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

Out of the box recoil will trigger updates after a shallow comparison when setting atom state. Is there a way to have the `atom` or `atomFamily` perform a deep comparison instead?

A workaround is to have an atom + selector factory, where the `set` function of the selector performs a deep comparison (see below). This works well, but has the limitation of not being usable within atomic Recoil transactions. (workaround credit to a github thread I can't seem to find)

```
export const createAtomWithDeepEqualityCheck = <T>(options: AtomOptions<T>) => {
  const _atom = atom(options);

  const wrappedAtom = selector<T>({
    key: `selector-${options.key}`,
    cachePolicy_UNSTABLE: { eviction: 'most-recent' },
    get: ({ get }) => get(_atom),
    set: ({ get, set }, newValue) => {
      const currValue = get(_atom);
      if (_isEqual(currValue, newValue)) {
        return;
      }
      set(_atom, newValue);
    },
  });

  return wrappedAtom;
};
```